# How to read Strings from txt file into 2D array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have an assignment about Solar System and this code and it's only reads the text file i need the code to read the file and put the data from text file to Variables like every single line in one variable

***You Can Change the Code But Make it Simple for Me***

```
                 fileName = "C:\\Users\\thkraa\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SolarSystem\\src\\SolarSystem.in";
                try {

                    //Create object of FileReader
                    FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);

                    //Instantiate the BufferedReader Class
                    bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

                    String line;

                    // Read file line by line and print on the console
                    while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    }
                    System.out.println("The File Has Been Imported!!");

                    //Close the buffer reader
                    bufferReader.close();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error while reading file:" + e.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: Instead of printing it to the console ... Store it in a variable or an array

Comment: You put down some assignment, and code. But what is your question?

Comment: The key here is your already declared string variable named **line** and the **while** loop it's being used in. As soon as the while loop is entered (in code) the string variable **line** will hold the first line of your text file. It is within the **while** loop where you decide what you want to do with that specific line. If you want every line within the text file to be placed into a single string variable then you can declare and use another string variable (before the loop) and append each file line to that variable **within** the loop, something like: `myVar = myVar + line;`.